# iPhone asks to trust computer each time when tethering hotspot is on

Tags: iphone, ios, mac, security, tethering

When tethering hotspot is on, and I connect with my laptop via USB (in order to tether), I get asked each time to trust the computer which is annoying.

Latest iOS 13.2 17B84 ;  Mac OS Catalina 10.15.1 (19B88) .

Answer (score 1):

In the past when the trust store became corrupt, I would see this. Have you followed the reset location process listed by Apple?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202778

Once you do that, I would connect the phone without tethering enabled to just get a plain connect and make sure the computer and device are copacetic with reconnects that don’t prompt.

Once you’re past that, then try the tethering again.

Comment: nope, didn't work. I've reset the Location & privacy settings, switched off tethering, connected to computer it asked to trust, then disconnected, and when connecting it doesn't ask anymore. But then I switched tethering on, and it still asked to trust. Hopeless